# How to prevent users from resetting passwords to previously used passwords on wordpress site?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, passwords, password-recovery

I'm trying to prevent users on my wordpress site from using the same password twice or resetting to a previously used password.

I've tried two methods;

```
add_action('password_reset', 'password_reset_action', 10, 2);
function password_reset_action($user, $new_pass) {
    // Get the user's hashed password from the database
    $hashed_password = $user->user_pass;

    // Initialize the password hasher
    require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-phpass.php'; // Include the password hashing library
    $wp_hasher = new PasswordHash(8, true);

    // Hash the new entered password
    $new_hash_password = $wp_hasher->HashPassword(trim($new_pass));

    // Check if the new password matches the current password
    if ($wp_hasher->CheckPassword(trim($new_pass), $hashed_password)) {
        // Passwords match, so enqueue a JavaScript script to display the error message
        add_action('wp_footer', 'display_password_reset_error');
    }
}

function display_password_reset_error() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            var errorParagraph = document.createElement("p");
            errorParagraph.style.color = "red";
            errorParagraph.textContent = "You cannot use your current password. Please choose a different one.";
            document.getElementById("resetpassform").appendChild(errorParagraph);
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

I've tried checking if both passwords are the same and then using javascript to create a text which displays and tells the user that they can't use the same password but what it does is just redirect to the confirmation page telling the user their password has been successfully reset.

Comment: What is `wp_get_password_history` supposed to be? I can not find a function of that name via a Google search. What did it actually return, have you checked that?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why? Forcing people to keep coming up with new passwords from time to time usually results in people writing easier and easier passwords, or come up with some pattern so they easier can remember them, which also makes it easier for bad actors to figure it out. So in practice, it can make peoples accounts _less_ secure. If everyone used a password manager and generated passwords, it would be a different matter, but many people still don't.

Comment: @CBroe I've changed my code to; `add_action('password_reset', 'password_reset_action', 10, 2);
function password_reset_action($user, $new_pass) {
    // Get the user's hashed password from the database
    $hashed_password = $user->user_pass;

    // Initialize the password hasher
    require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-phpass.php'; // Include the password hashing library
    $wp_hasher = new PasswordHash(8, true);

    // Hash the new entered password
    $new_hash_password = $wp_hasher->HashPassword(trim($new_pass));

`

Comment: Continuation `// Check if the new password matches the current password
    if ($wp_hasher->CheckPassword(trim($new_pass), $hashed_password)) {
        // Passwords match, so enqueue a JavaScript script to display the error message
        add_action('wp_footer', 'display_password_reset_error');
    }
}

`

Comment: COntinuation `function display_password_reset_error() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            var errorParagraph = document.createElement("p");
            errorParagraph.style.color = "red";
            errorParagraph.textContent = "You cannot use your current password. Please choose a different one.";
            document.getElementById("resetpassform").appendChild(errorParagraph);
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}` Still doesn't work

Comment: That is hard to read in comments, so please edit the question and add it in there, properly formatted. And _"Still doesn't work"_ isn't much of a problem description we can do much with. What debugging have you done so far, and with what results?

Comment: @CBroe sorry for the mess earlier. I've edited the original question to have my current solution.

Comment: `password_reset` is just an action that will be executed in the `reset_password` function - but the result doesn't influence how the rest of this function behaves. Not even sure if the redirect is even triggered _by_ that function.